# How to avoid using volatile in Java

Tags: java, volatile

I have two threads sharing the same variable of type boolean. I discovered that I have to use volatile to guarantee the value is always read from main memory. But now I want to get rid of this volatile identifier, how can I achieve that? Is it true that I easily can extract my boolean property into an object. As the reference to object never change the thread will always access the correct value from the main memory. Will this work?

Comment: `AtomicBoolean`?

Comment: No this will not work, accessing the variable may cached if not volatile. Volatile is the simplest way to obtain coherence.

Comment: "But now I want to get rid of this volatile identifier" => Why?

Comment: By looking at the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.java) AtomicBoolean uses volatile behind the scene.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to break working code? Who is paying for this time-wasting on your part?

Comment: Right now my shared variable is static but it should not be static. I am working on an jee application and the shared variable is part of a singleton bean. If I remove the static identifier it seems not working anymore.

Comment: Basicly all the statements in your question are false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have to use volatile to guarantee the value is always read from
>   main memory

That is not how `volatile` work.  `volatile` is used to build a `happens-before` relation ship:

> This means that changes to a volatile variable are always visible to
>   other threads. What's more, it also means that when a thread reads a
>   volatile variable, it sees not just the latest change to the volatile,
>   but also the side effects of the code that led up the change.

—— From the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html).

> But now I want to get rid of this volatile identifier, how can I
>   achieve that?

Like said in another answer, you can use `AtomicBoolean`. Or, add `synchronized` block around the code reading/writing this variable. Or use some other [mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html), as well as they can build a `happens-before` relation ship between reading and writing this varibale in different threads.

> Is it true that I easily can extract my boolean property into an
>   object. As the reference to object never change the thread will always
>   access the correct value from the main memory. Will this work?

No. The reference do not change, this does not mean the fresh object is always visible to other reading threads after it is updated.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use AtomicBoolean instead if you do not like the keyword - also this will allow write access to be thread safe too